# I need to return null as a value of key called null, but it keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, null, key-value

I have a parseJSON function whose result is supposed to exactly match the result of invoking JSON.parse when passed the same input. I have a helper function called getParsed() that parses strings into their proper types. My issue:

`parseJSON('{"boolean, true": true, "boolean, false": false, "null": null }')`
// returns `{boolean, true: true, boolean, false: false, null: undefined}`

I need the last property to return as

`null: null`

in order to match the result of JSON.parse()

I'm sure there is something about the nature of null that I'm missing here, but I can't find a way to fix the issue. Code snippet below (as of now the function only deals with objects literals).

```
var getParsed = str => {
  // Check if string is a number. Checks for floating point and integer
  if (/^-?\d*\.?\d+$/.test(str)) {
    if (str.includes('.')) {
      return parseFloat(str);
    } else {
      return parseInt(str);
    }
  }
  // Check if string is surrounded by quotes, wwill remain a string.
  if (/"[^"]*()[^"]*"/.test(str)) {
    var arr = str.split('');
    arr.pop();
    arr.shift();
    return arr.join('');
  }
  // Check if string is boolean
  if (str === 'true') { return true; }
  if (str === 'false') { return false; }
  // Check if string is false
  if (str === 'null' || str === 'undefined') { return null; }
};



var parseJSON = function (json, invoked = false) {
  if (json.startsWith('{')) {
    var arr = json.split('');
    var first = arr.shift();
    var last = arr.pop();
    var props = arr.join('').split(', ');
    var res = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      if (!props[i].includes(':')) {
        props[i] = props[i] + ', ' + props[i + 1];
        props.splice(i + 1, 1);
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      var prop = props[i].split(': ');
      var key = prop[0];
      var val = prop[1];

      if (key.includes('"')) {
        key = key.split('');
        key.shift();
        key.pop();
        key = key.join('');
        res[key] = getParsed(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
};
```

Comment: you may have a look into ste standard: [JSON](https://json.org/)

Comment: You are using `JSON.parse(val)` in your parser, why not just use it for the whole object?

Comment: @LukeStorry my bad. That was just something I was trying as a stop gap. I changed the snippet to reflect what I'm trying to make work. exchanged the JSON.parse() invocation back to getParsed() helper function.

Comment: Ah makes more sense, was wondering why the code was just working! ha

Comment: Can you explain why you do this when there is a native function in JavaScript? Parsing JSON is not a simple task. Your function will fail for lots of other inputs

Comment: @trincot This is for an assignment. I understand how superfluous it is lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting this:

```
console.log({str:str, test: (str === 'null')})
```

at the first line of `getParsed`, you will see your issue.

```
{str: 'null ', test: false}
```

So your final test in that function was failing, and then because it didn;t return anything, you were getting a `undefined` value in your final object.

Make sure you strip your spaces off and it'll work :)

Comment: I feel so dumb.

Comment: Ah, don't! Took me a while to figure it out, especially as when it is normally console.logged it came out as "null", only spotted it when I put it in that object.
Also if something near `if` statement isn't working as expected, the first thing I'd do is log the test in the `if` to see if it is actually `true`